# Subclass printing for the Foor loop

Tags: java

**Subclass Printing**
*Shopping cart*

Im currently making a shopping cart, i have created a 3 subclasses, Food, Drink, and Candy, all with different variables. And with one Product class (extends). In my main class i have added an ArrayList called inventory. so basiscally

```
private static ArrayList<Product> inventory = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

Now I'm stuck at the part where I want to print the specific product details within the 3 subclasses. I created a print methods for all 3 subclasses, but it only takes in the print method for ONLY the product(extends) class.

```
private static void printProduct()
{
    for(Product f: inventory)
    {
        System.out.println(f.getProductId() + "\t" + f.getProductName() + "\t \t" + f.getPrice());
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Please choose a Product by ID to view more Details");
    int chosenProduct = input.nextInt();
    for(Product p: inventory)
    {
        if (chosenProduct==p.getProductId())
        {
            p.
        }
    }
}
```

*Heres an example of a a subclass, I just copy and pasted the printfood method to this class to see if it would work. (it doesnt)*

```
public class Food extends Product{

private String brand;
private int protein;
private int carbs;
private int fats;


public Food()
{
    
}
public void printPoduct()
{
    System.out.println("Product ID:\t" + getProductId());
    System.out.println("Product Name:\t" + getProductName());
    System.out.println("Brand:\t" + brand);
    System.out.println("Quantity:\t" + getQuantity());
    System.out.println("Price:\t" + getPrice());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Calories:\t "+ getCalories());
    System.out.println("Carbohydrates: " + carbs);
    System.out.println("Protein:\t " + protein);
    System.out.println("Fats:\t " + fats );
}
```

*Heres the Product class, This is linked with the inventory Arraylist*

```
public class Product implements Serializable{ 
private int productId;
private String productName;
private int quantity;
private double price;
private int calories;
private boolean inStock;
private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L; //Specify Version

public Product()
{
    
}
public void printPoduct()
{
    System.out.println("Product ID:\t" + getProductId());
    System.out.println("Product Name:\t" + getProductName());
    System.out.println("Brand:\t" + brand);
    System.out.println("Quantity:\t" + getQuantity());
    System.out.println("Price:\t" + getPrice());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Calories:\t "+ getCalories());
    System.out.println("Carbohydrates: " + carbs);
    System.out.println("Protein:\t " + protein);
    System.out.println("Fats:\t " + fats);

    
        
    
}
```

Comment: do you get an error? please elaborate.

Comment: I'm confused. Please show the classes in your hierarchy and show how the `print` method is used.

Comment: its not really an error, Its just i dont know the code to call a method from a subclass that doesnt need to go through the Product class. because the For loop is calling from the Product class. Please advise? Thanks

Comment: @CarlPeralta if the method is specific to a given sub-class then your only choice is to cast it to that specific type. probably a good time to look your design model as well and decide whether you want to carry on doing things like that or refactor.

Comment: @CarlPeralta show the other classes aswell to better illustrate your description.